# Running nvprof --metrics command under windows gives an error：cuda profiling error

Tags: cuda, metrics, nvprof

Running nvprof --metrics command under windows gives an error：

```
==6580== NVPROF is profiling process 6580, command: Project1.exe
==6580== Error: Internal profiling error 4292:1.
======== Error: CUDA profiling error.
```

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTAoy.png)

If I only use the nvprof command, no error will be reported：

```
F:\vstest\Project1\x64\Release>nvprof Project1.exe
==384== NVPROF is profiling process 384, command: Project1.exe
sumMatrixOnGPU2D <<<(512,512), (32,32)>>> elapsed 22 ms
==384== Profiling application: Project1.exe
==384== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   61.28%  538.11ms         2  269.06ms  260.98ms  277.13ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
                   36.29%  318.68ms         1  318.68ms  318.68ms  318.68ms  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
                    2.43%  21.364ms         1  21.364ms  21.364ms  21.364ms  sumMatrixOnGPU2D(float*, float*, float*, int, int)
      API calls:   56.77%  1.29771s         3  432.57ms  47.895ms  1.19911s  cudaMalloc
                   37.53%  857.94ms         3  285.98ms  261.20ms  319.19ms  cudaMemcpy
                    2.56%  58.617ms         1  58.617ms  58.617ms  58.617ms  cudaDeviceReset
                    2.13%  48.594ms         3  16.198ms  14.312ms  17.671ms  cudaFree
                    0.95%  21.732ms         2  10.866ms  275.60us  21.456ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    0.02%  512.70us         1  512.70us  512.70us  512.70us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.02%  359.30us        96  3.7420us     100ns  204.60us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.02%  347.80us         1  347.80us  347.80us  347.80us  cudaGetDeviceProperties
                    0.01%  180.60us         1  180.60us  180.60us  180.60us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  32.100us         1  32.100us  32.100us  32.100us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.00%  13.400us         1  13.400us  13.400us  13.400us  cudaSetDevice
                    0.00%  4.0000us         3  1.3330us     200ns  3.5000us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  3.9000us         1  3.9000us  3.9000us  3.9000us  cudaGetLastError
                    0.00%  1.1000us         2     550ns     200ns     900ns  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  1.0000us         1  1.0000us  1.0000us  1.0000us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.00%     300ns         1     300ns     300ns     300ns  cuDeviceGetUuid
                    0.00%     300ns         1     300ns     300ns     300ns  cuDeviceGetLuid
```

I would like to ask what is the problem, how can I use the command nvprof --metrics

Comment: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/internal-profiling-error-4292-1/80319

Comment: thank you.The content in this link is very helpful.

Comment: @talonmies do you want to provide an answer? I agree with your statements and would upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer.

I am adding the solution that worked me, as a reference for other people.

You need to open NVIDIA Control Panel (right-click on the desktop, and select it)
Desktop (from top menu) -> Enable Developer Settings.
Then, select
Developer (from the side tree) -> Manage GPU Performance Counters -> Allow Access to the GPU performance counters to all users.

The was well documented by NVidia before; now it is very hard to find.

Comment: this should be the accepted, this seems like a common issue and this fix works. It also fixes other error codes. I had 34040

Comment: Another option is to run the application as `sudo` or `root`